# Selenium Web Driver access Javascript global variable in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, selenium, functional-testing

I am trying to run a functional test in Python using Selenium, and I want to retrieve the value of a global variable in Javascript that has been declared on a certain page.

Normally `browser.execute_script("return globalVar;")` works fine, but this variable is declared within `$(document).ready(function(){`, and Selenium can't locate it.

So Selenium can return the variable when it's declared like this:

```
var globalvar = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
});
```

but not like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var globalvar = 0;
});
```

Is there anyway I can use Selenium to return the value of the javascript global variable from within the Jquery document ready?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a global variable. It is local to the scope of the anonymous function. So no, you can't access it.

Comment: Wow, I've been working in Jquery for too long. I completely looked over the fact that the document ready is a function itself.